# SQL: Error converting varchar to int

Tags: t-sql, datetime, datepart

I have a following conversion error

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '2016-October' to
>   data type int.

in the following statement:

```
declare @month varchar(20) = 'October'
select HolidayName, Holiday
from tblHoliday 
where PortfolioID = 2 and DATEPART(Year, Holiday) = case when @month is null then 2016 else convert(varchar,2016) + '-' + @Month end
```

What am I doing wrong and what is the right way to do something like this?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: The various values returned from a [`case`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) expression must all be compatible data types, i.e. either identical or ones for which implicit conversion is supported. Your choices of an integer and a string are not, sadly, compatible. Please note that the default length for `VarChar` is `1`. You may want to specify something larger, e.g. `VarChar(4)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to archive:

**Your scenario**

1. if `@month is null` --> search all value in year 2016
2. if `@month is not null` --> search all value with month and year

**Your issue:**

1. when `@month is not null`, your query will be:

   `... and DATEPART(Year, Holiday) = convert(varchar,2016) + '-' @Month`
   which is comparing between integer and varchar
2. There is no build in function in tsql that allow you to convert month name straight to integer, so a workaround is:

   `SELECT DATEPART(MM, @month + '01 2000')`
3. I don't think using `case...when...then` would work here since it compares differently in each of your scenario so i suggest using `if...else`

**Code sample**

```
declare @month varchar(20) = 'October'
if @month is null begin
    select HolidayName, Holiday
    from tblHoliday 
    where PortfolioID = 2
    and DATEPART(Year, Holiday) = 2016
end
else begin
    select HolidayName, Holiday
    from tblHoliday
    where PortfolioID = 2
    and DATEPART(Year, Holiday) = 2016
    and DATEPART(Month, Holiday) = DATEPART(MM, @month + '01 2000')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is at

```
DATEPART(Year, Holiday) = case when @month is null then 2016 else convert(varchar,2016) + '-' + @Month end
```

Datepart(year, holiday) gives you an integer value, but case when returns an integer or a string. In your statement 2016 cannot be evaluated to '2016-October'